# Overlap integrals in Hückel theory

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, physical-organic-chemistry

In Hückel theory we are only interested in π systems, where $\mathrm p_z$ orbitals *overlap*. One of the approximations in Hückel theory is that the overlapping $\mathrm p_z$ orbitals are orthonormal:

$$
S_{ij} =
\begin{cases}
1\quad i = j \\
0\quad i \neq j \\
\end{cases}
$$

If orbital overlap leads to bond formation, how can the overlap integrals, between $\mathrm p_z$ orbitals, be equal to 0? Maybe I am missing something obvious, but doesn't a π-bond demand non-zero overlap between p-orbitals?

Comment: You have the right idea, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%BCckel_method#Mathematics_behind_the_H%C3%BCckel_method): "This neglect of orbital overlap is an especially severe approximation. In actuality, orbital overlap is a prerequisite for orbital interaction, and it is impossible to have $H_{ij}=\beta$ while $S_{ij}=0$." So its just to make the math easier and you are correct that it makes the result less physically realistic.

Comment: The overlap of an orbital with itself is 1 for normalised orbitals and approx 0.25 for adjacent orbitals and less for those further away. Huckel made a dramatic assumption that the overlap is zero except for $i=j$. The simplicity and application to a range of important compounds has given this theory a surprising success. However, the expectation of accurate results should not be high.

Comment: I see, so in reality, there IS overlap. Just the calculations are simplified with this approximation. I wonder though, is this approximation absolutely mandatory? (i.e. can I evaluate the overlap integrals precisely, if I wanted to, while still using Hückel theory?)

Comment: @JamesBond There is the [Extended Hückel Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_H%C3%BCckel_method), which includes overlaps ([J. Chem. Phys. **39**, 1397 (1963)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1734456)).

Comment: @FelipeS.S.Schneider I initially thought Extended Hückel theory introduced overlap between the pi and sigma frameworks. I was not aware  that it also included the overlap between the p-orbitals!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hückel theory would still work if there would be overlap.

In fact, it is possible to create a completely new basis by applying a transformation to the basis set by which a new set of orthogonal basis functions is created. The advantage of setting $\hat{S}$ (the overlap matrix) to $\hat{I}$ (the identity matrix) is that the eigenvectors of the matrix equation can be directly interpreted in terms of the $\pi$ orbitals in the system.

There is the opposite view in [Extended Huckel Methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_H%C3%BCckel_method) whereby the assumption is that the overlap entries *depend* upon the off-diagonal elements. In ordinary Huckel theory, the diagonal elements are represented as 
\begin{align}
\alpha_{ii} &= \langle \psi_i | \hat{H} | \psi_i \rangle \\
\hat{H} &= -\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\nabla^2 + V
\end{align}

But in the extended thoery, the offdiagonal elements are not denoted by $\beta_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ but more as

\begin{align}
\beta_{ij} &= - \frac{C}{2}\Big \langle \psi_i \Big |-\frac{\hbar^2}{2}\nabla^2 + V \Big | \psi_j \Big \rangle\\
&= - \frac{C}{2} \left(\alpha_{ii} + \alpha_{jj} \right)S_{ij}
\end{align}
Where $S_{ij}$ is the usual notation for the overlap between the corresponding atomic orbitals.

Here $C$ is a constant, usually taken equal to $7/4$ and has units of energy.